# Can we have a mixed-type matrix in Matlab...and how?

Tags: matlab, types, matrix

I'm trying to write a function with a matrix (specifically a matrix) as the output, the rows of which show a double-type variable and a binary 'status'. For no real reason and just out of curiosity, I wonder if there is a way to have the rows to have different types.

Many Thanks

Comment: how about using cells?

Comment: @Bitwise sorry I didn't mention I tried cells, now I was trying to do that specifically for *matrices*...but I guess there's no way to do that.

Answer (score 7):

MATLAB offers two viable options for storing mixed data types:

#### Cell arrays

You can look at a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) as a special matrix where and each element (called *cell*) can be of a different type (and size). For instance:

```
C = {2, 'Hello'}
```

is a cell array that stores both a double and a string.

#### Structures

[Structures](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html) can also store values of different data types and sizes, each in a different *field*. For example, the information in the cell array above can be represented as a structure in the following way:

```
S.count = 2
S.name = 'Hello'
```

Recommendation:
It seems that a struct looks more elegant for your needs; I suppose you'll have a field called `status` storing a boolean value and a field called `number` storing a double. For multiple values you can store a vector of booleans in `status` and a vector of doubles in `number`. Alternatively you can have an array of structs holding one boolean and one double each.