# Create table from variables with original data sizes

Tags: matlab, matlab-table

I have a list of variables and its values which are of different datatypes (float32, uint32, int8 ....). Now I'm collecting them into a table:

```
T = [variable;variable2;variable3;variable4];
```

The variables in the tables are automatically casted to uint16. I would like to have the values in the original size. How can I say this to matlab when collecting the data to the table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we have a mixed-type matrix in Matlab...and how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844099/can-we-have-a-mixed-type-matrix-in-matlab-and-how)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use from `table` in matlab. For example:

```
T = table(categorical({'M';'F';'M'}),[45;32;34],...
{'NY';'CA';'MA'},logical([1;0;0]),...
'VariableNames',{'Gender' 'Age' 'State' 'Vote'});
```

Follow more details from [documentation on table data structure](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html).